# Python Equivalents of field.getInt(obj)

Tags: python

I'm wondering how is the python equivalent of this code:

```
Object owner;
Object target
String fieldname;
Field field = owner.getClass().getField(fieldname);
int i = field.getInt(target);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = getattr(target, fieldname)
```

See the documentation for [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr).